# JAVA double to string format

Tags: java, string, double, string-conversion

Suddenly I get an error which before I didnt have

Example:

```
Double double1 = 0.12;
String string1 = String.format("%.2f", double1)

System.out.println(string1);
```

Output:

```
0,12
```

Then I do this

```
double double2 = Double.parseDouble(string1);
```

Error

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0,12"
```

I'm pretty sure I comes because of the "," (comma). The funny thing is that two days ago anything was working fine and I didnt change anything.

Do know what happened or what I need to change?

Comment: `string1` is `0.12`, how did you get `0,12` ?

Comment: You changed the default locale of your application, or your OS. parseDouble() always expects a dot. String.format() uses the locale-dependant decimal separator. You shouldn't use the first one to parse something generated by the latter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Double#parseDouble` parses numbers in the format out put by `Double#toString`.

`String#format`, when asked to format a number with a decimal point, will output this in the current locale, but `Double#toString` will not.

If you want to parse the output of `String#format`, I believe that `Scanner` can do this. Personally, though, I would avoid localisation in numbers you expect to parse, and either use `Double#toString` to do the formatting, or explicitly pass `Locale.ROOT` when formatting it.

Comment: Regarding "Do you know what happened"  - default locale of the OS was changed (like mentioned by JB Nizet). It could've been mentioned explicitly in this answer as well, though I guess you implicitly say something like that.

Comment: Thats right, somewhere else in the code I used Locale.UK and that might have changed the application! Now I added Locale.US and now its working fine again!

Answer (score 0):

String cannot be converted to double

return String.format("%.5f",area);

I found this error while I was running my program.
It means my program needs an output in double datatype but the above error returns the string datatype so now we need to convert the string to double. For this, we use the below methods

```
Double.parseDouble(String.format("%.5f",area));
Double.valueOf(String.format("%.5f",area));
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35451099)